# What Lego-like head is this, with a blue slit over the eyes?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands, minifigure-identification

It has no facial features. Has a blue slit. No helmet and no hair
[image: Lego-like head is this, with a blue slit over the eyes]

Comment: That's not Lego - the chin shape gives it away. I think Kreo makes that shape, but I don't know if anyone else does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the lead from RSchulz that this might be Kreo, I found this head in the Dinobot Slug Custom Kreon set.
[image]

Comment: Nice! I looked at a lot of Kreon heads, but never saw that one.

Comment: @RSchulz I actually found [Scorn](https://kreo.fandom.com/wiki/Scorn_(Custom_Kreon)) first, but I wasn't 100% sure it was the same head, so I was looking for photos without the helmet.